# R purrr:::pmap: how to refer to input arguments by name?

Tags: r, purrr, tidyverse

I am using R `purrr:::pmap` with three inputs. It is not clear how I can refer explicitly to these inputs in the *formula* call? When using map2, the *formula* call goes as `~ .x + .y`. But how to do when using `pmap`?

Reproducing Hadley's example from http://r4ds.had.co.nz/lists.html

```
library(purrr)
mu <- list(5, 10, -3)
sigma <- list(1, 5, 10)
n <- list(1, 3, 5)

args2 <- list(mean = mu, sd = sigma, n = n)
pmap(args2, rnorm)
```

If I want to refer explicitly to the input arguments when calling `rnorm`, I can use:

```
pmap(args2, function(mean, sd, n) rnorm(n, mean, sd))
```

But say I want to do this with the *formula* approach. How do I do that? This for example does not work:

```
pmap(args2, ~rnorm(n=.n, mean=.mean, sd=.sd))
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `with(...)` to solve this :

```
pmap(args2, ~with(list(...),rnorm(n, mean, sd)))
# [[1]]
# [1] 2.733528
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 4.0967533 6.4926143 0.6083532
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  1.8836592 -0.2090425 -4.0030168  1.1834931  3.2771316
```

More explanations here: [Harnessing .f list names with purrr::pmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51122773/harnessing-f-list-names-with-purrrpmap/51123520#51123520)

Comment: elegant solution, nice!

Answer (score 17):

Since [version 0.2.3](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/releases/tag/v0.2.3) you can use `..1`, `..2`, `..3` and so on:

```
pmap(args2, ~ rnorm(..3, ..1, ..2))
```

---

But... I've already ran into trouble with this syntax, for instance with `replicate`:

```
pmap(list(1, 2), ~ replicate(n = ..1, expr = ..2))
# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : the ... list does not contain 2 elements
```

Probably because of:

```
print(replicate)
# function (n, expr, simplify = "array") 
#   sapply(integer(n), eval.parent(substitute(function(...) expr)), 
#          simplify = simplify)
```

It seems the `function(...) expr` in `substitute()` does not play well with `..2`, being interpreted as the second element of `...` which is empty.

Note that `pmap(list(1, 2), ~ replicate(n = ..1, expr = .y))` still works.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `pmap` cannot access the arguments in a list by its name in the formula interface.
You can check in https://github.com/hadley/purrr/issues/203.

For instance you can do :

```
pmap(list(1:2, 5:6), ~ .x + .y)
```

Thus the first element of the list is referred by `.x`and the second by `.y`.
However if you try to name the argument of the list as in

```
pmap(list(a = 1:2, b =  5:6), ~ .a + .b)
```

then you will have the error:

```
Error in .f(a = .l[[c(1L, i)]], b = .l[[c(2L, i)]], ...) : 
  unused arguments (a = .l[[c(1, i)]], b = .l[[c(2, i)]])
```

I think that in the formula interface of the function `pmap` the best you could do if you want to use the formula interface and not use `function(mean , sd, n)` is to :

1. not name the elements of your list
2. not use more than two arguments (in order to use the implicit name `.x` and `.y`)

You can thus use thus fix the value of your third argument `n` (for instance `n = 4`) you want and then run:

```
mu <- list(5, 10, -3)
sigma <- list(1, 5, 10)
set.seed(1)
pmap(list(mu,sigma), ~ rnorm(mean = .x, sd = .y, n = 4))
```

Which will return :

```
[[1]]
[1] 4.373546 5.183643 4.164371 6.595281

[[2]]
[1] 11.647539  5.897658 12.437145 13.691624

[[3]]
[1]  2.7578135 -6.0538839 12.1178117  0.8984324

[[4]]
[1]  9.136278  4.355900 14.374793 10.865199
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great to see the link in particular! Unfortunately, just using 2 inputs is not really a solution in my case :-(

Comment: Yes I agree, using just 2 inputs is lesser evil but still not satisfactory.
At least you can use the approach with the `function(mean, sd, n)`; by the way do you absolutely want to use the formula approach ?